# Google analytics implementation on Swift-iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

Can you help me and provide how exactly to implement GA to Swift-based iOS app?

I am trying do this: `GAI.h lib import`, but it doesn't work correctly. 
`GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtException = true` doesn't work as well because  it is `unknown method`

Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you did (tried)?

Comment: I want integrate GA in to Swift-based iOS app.

Comment: I understand your desire to integrate GA. I did it a while ago and I am certainly not sure I can help, but I (and others) would have better chance if you describe your steps and the error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of late, but still for those having the same question:

In your `[AppName]-Bridging-Header.h` (explained [here](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-an-objective-c-bridging-header/) how to add) you would need to import those parts of Google Analytics you need for your project like this:

```
#ifndef [AppName]_Pregnant_Bridging_Header_h

...
#import "[GA folder name]/GAI.h"
#import "[GA folder name]/GAITrackedViewController.h"
...

#endif
```

The Google Analytics SDK should now be properly imported for use.